# How do I change the default Icon of Atom editor on a Ubuntu?

Tags: customization, ubuntu-14.04, atom-editor

My question is about changing default atom.icns file of the editor, I just don't know where I can find it in a Ubuntu OS. A find some instructions for mac, but I could find for Ubuntu yet.

PS: I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The icon is stored here (along with the icons for many other things):

`/usr/share/pixmaps/atom.png`

Just swap it out for a different image. (I went with this one https://dribbble.com/shots/1443056-Atom-Icon)

Note: this won't persist through upgrades to atom.

Edit: It seems in the latest version of atom this doesn't work any more :(